# Projection onto a symplex

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorial-geometry

Suppose we have $n$ vectors in an $m$-dimensional vector space such that their span is all the space and none of them are zero. We choose any hyperplane which does not pass through zero and project these points from the origin onto it.

Is it true that we can always choose a hyperplane in such a way that the convex hull of the images of our points under projection is a symplex?